# How does $\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}$ become $\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{2\cos^2(x/2)}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am new to calculus.

[image]

How?

thanks in advance

Comment: See http://www.sosmath.com/trig/douangl/douangl.html

Comment: The question is unclear, what is it that you want to understand?

Comment: Do you understand the previous equation?

Comment: yes i dont no how 2 sin got in there

Comment: I would recommend to first understand how to calculate the sines and cosines of sums of angles. Namely, understand why
$$
\sin{(x \pm y)} = \sin{x}\cos{y} \pm \cos{x}\sin{y}
$$
When this is clear, you can plug in $x=y$ etc ...

Comment: sorry guys i didn't study the identities . that is why i didn't understand this .

Comment: i just started learning continuity and differentiation . Right now i am studying derivative inverse trigonometric functions and this is the first question of that topic .

Comment: @SachinRamesh: Often, the hardest part of learning Calculus is remembering all the stuff you were supposed to have learned *before* Calculus. So, you may want to brush-up on your trigonometry. Wikipedia has a [long list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) of trig identities you may find helpful. (Your question amounts to an application of the [half-angle identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae).)

Comment: thank you , i will study it all :)

Comment: stay blessed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1- \cos x=1-\cos(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2})=1-(\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}))=1-(1-\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}))+\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})=2 \sin^2(\frac{x}{2}).$

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

$$\cos(2\theta)\equiv 1-2\sin^2(\theta)\equiv2\cos^2(\theta)-1$$